# Is there a good admin generator for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My current project is in Rails.  Coming from a Symfony (PHP) and Django (Python) background, they both have excellent admin generators.  Seems like this is missing in Rails.

For those who aren't familiar with Symfony or Django, they both allow you to specify some metadata around your models to automatically (dynamically) generate an admin interface to do the common CRUD operations.  You can create an entire Intranet with only a few commands or lines of code.  They have a good appearance and are extensible enough for 99% of your admin needs.

I've looked for something similar for Rails, but all of the projects either have no activity or they died long ago.  Is there anything to generate an intranet/admin site for a rails app other than scaffolding?

Comment: This is off-topic but there's no way to send a private message in Stack Overflow, so I'll ask here. I'm also coming from symfony and just getting started with Rails. What has your overall experience been with Rails compared to symfony? Was Rails easy to learn because symfony borrowed so many of its ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scaffolding is the normal way to create an admin backend BUT there is a project called [ActiveScaffold](http://www.activescaffold.com/) which may solve your problem.

Comment: ActiveScaffold looks exactly like what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Beware using ActiveScaffold, the views are immensely complex, and there's problems with supporting the latest rails.

Comment: ActiveScaffold is pretty old and complex to use now. As of April 2011, rails_admin is preferable.

Answer (score 47):

**Active Admin** (http://activeadmin.info/) was released in May of 2011, and looks like it's going to become the best Rails 3 option.

[image: features]

Comment: in which case it worth to check out [railscasts284](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin)

Comment: ActiveAdmin is by far the best option for Rails 3.

Answer (score 20):

[rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) appears to be the latest-n-greatest free project as of January 2011.

...best of all, there has been a lot of activity in the repository.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/07/rails-admin-interface-roundup/) is a roundup of a few options, including more than just ActiveScaffold.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveScaffold is available for Rails 2.3.x :)
Just for someonse's info who have found this question one year later like me :)

Answer (score 3):

ActiveScaffold is a good solution, but if you want a more configurable and powerful tool, I think Typus is a great solution:
http://github.com/fesplugas/typus

Answer (score 2):

You have mainly two:

- [ActiveScaffolding](http://www.activescaffold.com/): the most popular but [be careful with rails 2.1](http://www.concept47.com/austin_web_developer_blog/ruby-on-rails/current-active-scaffold-rails-plugin-111-not-compatible-with-rails-21/)
- [Streamlined](http://streamlinedframework.org/)

Answer (score 2):

ActiveScaffold is by far and away the most configurable/easiest to integrate/most automagic scaffolding around at the moment.
It has built in ajax support, near seamless db introspection and it even plays nicely with legacy Oracle databases (which can be a real pain in Rails).

Try it: http://activescaffold.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Casein (http://www.caseincms.com/), might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Having also tried typus, caseincms and ActiveScaffold over the weekend, I can't rave enough about [admin_data](https://github.com/neerajdotname/admin_data).
It is

- super-quick to install (Rails 3 is the gem, Rails 2.3 is a plugin branch, 
  no digging through trees on github),
- unintrusive (all code is in the    vendor/admin_data folder or the gem where it belongs),
- requires no set-up and optional configuration is one block in one file in your app,
- correctly (!) gets all model information from your model definitions (primary_key, foreign_key, relationships etc.),
- including multiple databases, SQL Server connections via activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, and even [composite primary keys](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/), as everything is abstracted on top of ActiveRecord, if you model works, admin_data will work,
- works great with legacy data for the above reasons,
- uses your existing authentication solution which is called in the most wonderful DRYness in your configuration file.
  It maybe less flexible or pretty than other solutions, but this plugin does many thingks right for quick admin panel setup.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to create a CRUD interface is to use Scaffold.

```
./script/generate scaffold_resource MyModel property:type property2:type2
```

This command would generate a CRUD interface for the model named MyModel (singular) with two properties. Properties is what's called columns in DB lingo. So you could have name:string age:integer active:boolean etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you `active_admin` that is best

[Active Admin main site](http://activeadmin.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Now a decade later there's a really fast admin panel type thing that's available -- **[The Brick](https://github.com/lorint/brick)**. This one auto-creates its own models / controllers / views when any existing ones are not found, and does this entirely on-the-fly in RAM.

Not as configurable as other panels, but it's lean and works with all manner of Rails associations -- of course the common belongs_to and has_many, but also polymorphics and single table inheritance.