# Web application admin generators

Tags: php, python, ruby, frameworks

Since [**Symfony 1.x's admin generator**](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/14-Generators), I found this kind of tool really useful to prototype applications, show something very quickly to customers etc.

Now for **Symfony2**, admin generator does not seems to be a priority (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/N1wlvj1F5Eo/discussion) and [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/AdminBundle))

[**Django**'s admin generator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) seems very interesting...

Which web application admin generator (any language / technology) would you recommend (pros / cons)?

Comment: I think Djangos scaffolding is the best, but I have no hard data to back that up so that is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Why is there a bounty on this? There is no right answer, what people like best is personal.

Comment: I agree it is somewhat personal, but some generators can be very limited compared to others. I'm looking for a good app generator, simple to configure and use, and not limited to "basic CRUD" (e.g. abilities to handle one-to-many, many-to-many relationships).
I started the bounty because I got no answer two days after asking the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django's automatic admin app is excellent.  Once you've written your models, it automatically creates a full-featured admin app around them where you can create, update and delete records.  It's also extensible and customizable for just about whatever you need.

Here's a [pretty good overview about it](http://devpicayune.com/pycon2008/django_admin.html).  Django (and python) is intuitive and satisfying to work with -- I highly recommend that you set it up and play with it and see how well it works.

Comment: Additional resource: the **Chapter of Django Manual about the Django Admin Site** http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/

Comment: Another one: **Django 1.3 Admin doc** http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 7):

**Updated 2017**

[Agile UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui) (a successor of atk4.3) is an MIT based PHP UI Component library. It gives your application nice looking, consistent User Interface without you have to write any HTML and works with any PHP framework or application.

> Demo: http://ui.agiletoolkit.org/demos/index.php

The reason I think this is better than a built-in generator:

- Almost no dependencies, works with any framework or PHP app.
- Can work with SQL or NoSQL, relies on [Agile Data](https://git.io/ad).
- Stylish, modern and responsive. ([Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/))
- Interactive. "Form" uses JS to submit, display in-line validation. "CRUD" uses modal windows, pagination and QuickSearch.
- Extensible. Need charts? https://github.com/atk4/chart.
- Open-source

To build a minimalistic application admin you only need 15 lines of PHP code:

```
<?php
$app = new \atk4\ui\App('My App');
$app->initLayout(new \atk4\ui\Layout\Admin());

$db = \atk4\data\Persistence::connect($DSN);

class User extends \atk4\data\Model {
    public $table = 'user';
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('email', ['required'=>true]);
        $this->addField('password', ['type'=>'password']);
    }
}
$app->layout->add(new \atk4\ui\CRUD())
  ->setModel(new User($db));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice and promising piece of work. I like its concepts of usability for end-users as well as for developers.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I have found Yii's scaffolding is the best there is. [Quick First Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app)

What I truly loved:

- Controlled creation of files. Yii provides an interface to create all required files, called Gii.
- You have the ability to generate your model classes based on the database model.
- You have the ability to generate CRUD operations for all your model classes (Action methods for your controller class).

The generated scaffolding includes: Pagination, Searching, Advanced Searching, Listening, Inserting and Updating includes validation out of the box, Deleting. And all of the interface is ajax driven.

Comment: Symfony2 Admin Generator and the Django Admin is not scaffolding. Scaffolding violates the DRY principle. It's just automated copy & paste.

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby on Rails: [Here is some discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383/is-there-a-good-admin-generator-for-ruby-on-rails)

But ActiveScaffold's home page at the moment is still talking about Rails 2.3, so you may want to read past the accepted answer and check the others to see if there are newer ones.

[Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) looks to be actively developed and has good pedigree (having been a Google Summer of Code project mentored by big names in the Rails community, so I'd start there if I were looking.

Comment: I have been using rails_admin for last few months and really satisfied with it. Recent support of CanCan has increased its appeal.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend CakePHP [scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1103/Scaffolding), where you can also add [admin routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1104/Creating-a-simple-admin-interface-with-scaffolding). Nice for you is that you can stay on PHP, which you also used for Symphony. Be warned, you might get addicted to Cake ;)

Answer (score 2):

something a lot more powerful for CakePHP is https://github.com/josegonzalez/cake_admin, little bit of a Django rip-off :)

Answer (score 1):

I like [sprox](http://sprox.org/), for Python. Although I have not found it particularly useful for production, it can help a lot in terms of prototyping and testing -- its simplicity is its strength here, enhancing Python's own strengths.

Answer (score 1):

[Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) has "Padrino Admin":

http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/padrino-admin

While not as popular as Rails, it's built around the excellent [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) DSL.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails applications, [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/) with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is the best solution as of now. These are very actively maintained and supports Rails 3.0. With CanCan, you can customize access on models. So that you can easily set multiple level of admins/authors. Previously I have used [ActiveScaffold](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold) for 2.0 application but it doesn't seem to support newest Rails.