# Is there a good php form generator that also validates data

Tags: php, forms, generator, validation

Hey guys I would like to save some time....is there a form generator that will have functions to validate the data?

I don't want it to look pretty just normal text boxes and what not. No graphics. No javascript.

If there is would help me out BIG time.

Comment: If you are respecting principles of decoupling, then you should not mix form generation and input validation logic. However, you can use two libraries, each for the respective purpose. I have written https://github.com/gajus/dora for form generation and https://github.com/gajus/vlad for input validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly simple solution http://phpfmg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What it generates is too much I want it like it was created without a generator just so it's like normal.

Answer (score 1):

http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout http://formbakery.com. It's a php email form generator.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this SO question: [Web application admin generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460011/web-application-admin-generators)

[Django Admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/) could help you for this task. See especially section "[Adding custom validation to the admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin)".